# Difference between static variable inside and outside of a function?

Tags: c++, syntax, static, keyword

```
static int count;

int main()
{

 static int count;    

}
```

Is there any difference between static variables declared inside and outside any function?

(I mean the **scope and visibility** of the variable count)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your first `count` is only accessible within the module (code in that file). Your second `count` is only accessible within `main`.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare outside of method it will be available to *all <del>static method</del> functions written after its declaration*. While declaring static variable in method will be accessible by *only that method*.

Comment: -1: Incorrect. static at file scope is *not* the same as static in a class definition.

Comment: @Erik: will you explain a little more? Let me know where I'm wrong?

Comment: @Erik: I think you misread him. I don't see any problem with his explanation!

Comment: @Harry Joy: There's no class definition in the OP. The `static int count` outside his `int main` will be visible to *all code following it, in the same TU* - there's no requirement on the functions that have access to it. So, "*all static method written after its declaration*" is incorrect.

Comment: @Erik: Alright. He should say *"all functions written after its declaration"*.

Comment: @Nawaz: No, a method implies a class member function. And the variable isn't only accessible to functions - it could also be used to e.g. initialize other variables.

Comment: @Erik: Alright. Functions. As for initializing other variables, he didn't say that it cannot be done!

Comment: @Harry Joy: It's still not 100% correct - but at least it's not flat out wrong now. Removed the -1.

Comment: @Nawaz: The file-scope count is available to *everything* following it, within the same TU, regardless of whether it's a function or not. And he still uses that horrible 'method' word :P

Answer (score 3):

There's also a difference in dynamic initialization of globals (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239235/how-lazy-can-c-global-initialization-be)).  To summarize, if you had:

```
static int count = bar();

int main ()
{
  static int count = foo ();
}
```

The call to 'foo' will take place when main is executed, but the standard (C++ '03) doesn't require a call to 'bar' at all!